# Finding the distinct values of a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `GroupSummary` `class` that has some properties like this in it:

```
public class GroupsSummary
{
    public bool FooMethod()
    {
      ////
    }
    public bool UsedRow { get; set; }

    public string GroupTin   { get; set; }
    public string PayToZip_4 { get; set; }
    public string PayToName  { get; set; }

    public string PayToStr1     { get; set; }
    public string PayToStr2     { get; set; }
    public string PayToCity     { get; set; }
    public string PayToState    { get; set; }
    public bool   UrgentCare_YN { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a `Dictionary` like `<string, List<GroupsSummary>`

For each of these dictionary items I want to find all the **distinct** addresses but the properties of this class that define a distinct address for me are

```
PayToStr1,PayToStr2,PayToCity,PayToState
```

I know as far as I can say something like `mydictionartItem.select(t => t).Distinct().ToList()`   but I think that will compare all the properties of this class which is wrong. So how should I solve this?

Comment: Implement `IEquatable<T>` for `GroupsSummary` or else you can use the version of `Distinct` that takes an `IEqualityComparer<TSource>`. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: You could also create a readonly property of `address` in your class being the conglomeration of only those properties you want and just use that property for the lambda expression...

Comment: how about "GroupBy" ? Can do that instead of implementing IEquatable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var newDict = dict.ToDictionary(
                    x=>x.Key, 
                    v=>v.Value.GroupBy(x=>new{x.PayToStr1, x.PayToStr2, x.PayToCity, x.PayToState})
                              .Select(x=>x.First())
                              .ToList());
```

Comment: it says the type arguments cannot be inferred from the usage. So when I type x.  it doesn't find any property. Also red line under groupBy

Comment: @user1899082 It should work for a dictionary `Dictionary<string,List<GroupsSummary>>`. Are you sure you use that type of dict as you posted in question?

Comment: my dic is defined like this: "Dictionary<string, List<GroupsSummary>> groupsDictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<GroupsSummary>>();"

Answer (score 2):

implement `IEquatable<T>` interface on the `GroupsSummary` Class. More information can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx)

IEquatable 
defines a method `Equals`. Remember to overload the `GetHashCode` method as well

Answer (score 2):

Write your own `IEqualityComparer`, like so:

```
    public class GroupsSummaryComparer : IEqualityComparer<GroupsSummary>
    {
        public bool Equals(GroupsSummary x, GroupsSummary y)
        {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, y))
                return true;
            else if (object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;

            return x.PayToStr1 == y.PayToStr1 && x.PayToStr2 == y.PayToStr2 && x.PayToCity == y.PayToCity && x.PayToState == y.PayToState;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(GroupsSummary obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
                return 0;
            int code;
            if (obj.PayToStr1 != null)
                code ^= obj.PayToStr1.GetHashCode();
            if (obj.PayToStr2 != null)
                code ^= obj.PayToStr2.GetHashCode();
            if (obj.PayToCity != null)
                code ^= obj.PayToCity.GetHashCode();
            if (obj.PayToState != null)
                code ^= obj.PayToState.GetHashCode();
            return code;
        }
    }
```

Then you can pass it to [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

This may be safer than implementing [`IEquatable<GroupsSummary>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directly on the class, since, in other situations, you may want to test them for full equality.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to implement an [`IEqualityComparer<GroupsSummary>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx)

Then you can say something like

```
HashSet<GroupSummary> unique = new HashSet<GroupsSummary>(
  myDict.Values ,
  new MyGroupsSummaryEqualityComparer()
  ) ;
```

Comment: The original data source is `Dictionary<string, List<GroupsSummary>>`. With this approach, it won't be possible to associate each unique address with the original `string` key. This will simply return a set of all of the unique addresses in the original `Dictionary`. Perhaps not quite what the OP wants, but concise and easy to understand.