# Suggested structure to maps some strings to some other strings

Tags: c#, string, collections, keyvaluepair

In my console application I have one hundred county codes and their names. For example:

```
"01" : "Floyd"
"02" : "Wabash"
```

When my program uses the values, it reads "01","02"...and I want to get "Floyd", etc...

This list won't grow in future, I am just hard coding them, How do you suggest to access these?
Maybe in a static class? Maybe in a JSON format?  Other ways?

Comment: what puzzles me, is that you're aware of dictionaries, as your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25087266/1698987) suggests

Comment: @Noctis My ID says it all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple [`Dictionary<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx); if you really want you can wrap it in a class to add some behavior such as handling keys not found, or already existing

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary is what you look for: [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Short example:

```
void Main()
{
    var dic = new Dictionary<int,string>();

    // Instead of having a method to check, we use this Action
    Action<int> tryDic = (i) => {
        if (dic.ContainsKey(i))
            Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, dic[i]);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("dic has no key {0}", i);
    };

    dic.Add(1,"one");
    dic.Add(2,"two");

    // dic.Keys   = 1, 2
    // dic.Values = one, two

    tryDic(1); // one
    tryDic(3); // dic has no key 3 (Happens in Action above)

    dic[1]="wow";
    tryDic(1); // wow

}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could remove the Dump calls;, even if Linqpad is pretty awesome it distracts from your answer

Comment: @samy Fine ... be that way ... :) ... brushed it up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a `Dictionary<string, string>`

```
var values = new Dictionary<string,string>();
values.Add("01", "Floyd");
...

var value = values["01"]; // Floyd
```